# Ephedra diet pill availability

Tags: weight-loss, supplements

A while back I used to take a pill called Stacker 2 a herbal supplement with ephedra. I found it gave me a lot of energy and helped me lose a significant amount of weight. There was a while  after a football player who abused Epedra  died of a heart attack and there a knee jerk response to this players irresponsibility it became illegal. Then a year later it became legal again.

I was wondering is there an equivalent Herbal supplementation available with ephedra on the market currently or did Stacker 2 reintroduce ephedra back into the formula again after removing with the change of the law, or does anyone have any other supplementation that does the same trick that some one could provide with info with?

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed for several reasons. I don't think it fits in the current version of the [faq], the substance in question seems to be illegal and it is a shopping question after all.

Comment: Obviously I fudged up the first _don't_ in the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from Wikipedia:

*On August 17, 2006, the Appeals Court upheld the FDA's ban of ephedra, finding that the 133,000 page administrative record compiled by the FDA supported the agency's finding that ephedra posed an unreasonable risk to consumers. Nutraceutical Corp. filed a petition for a writ of certiorari seeking a rehearing on the ban of ephedra; however, on May 14, 2007 the United States Supreme Court declined to hear this petition. **The sale of ephedra-containing dietary supplements remains illegal in the United States.***

Sorry bro. The effective ingredient of ephedra, ephedrine, is available in pharmacies on prescription, but if you go there you might as well get amphetamines or Ritalin...I suggest you let it go.

Comment: that's funny I could have sworn they reversed it

Comment: I guess I remember this

Comment: Judge Tena Campbell of the Utah Federal District Court ruled that the FDA had not proven that low doses of ephedra were unsafe, although she also noted that studies to address the safety of low-dose ephedra would be unethical. Nevertheless, her ruling overturned the ban on the sale of ephedra in the state of Utah, and called into question whether the ban could be enforced anywhere in the United States.